# mongo local server uninstallition

Tags: mongodb, uninstallation, ubuntu-18.04

I'm try to uninstall mongod but it's give
message of file / package missing 
during installation it's show message
of no newly file install ...............

```
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb is already the newest version (1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ mongod
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4627 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=dz-gg-04
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-10-19T15:25:00.599+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-10-19T15:25:00.600+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2018-10-19T15:25:00.600+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-10-19T15:25:00.600+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-10-19T15:26:04.016+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-10-19T15:26:04.016+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ sudo service mongod start 
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ ^C
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ ^C
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ ^C
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ ^C
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ ^C
dz-gg-04@dz-gg-04:~$ sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

Create the directory /data/db